# Can we save C structure in Redis by hiredis ? I can save it but can not get it

Tags: c, linux, redis

I want to know if I could save a C structure in redis. But I do not know how to get it because the example.c in hiredis do not mentioned that.

I save a structure to Redis using binary-safe string. And I got a +OK which means I save that correctly.

The save code is here

```
...
reply = redisCommand(c, "HMSET %s stat %b", rcvgetattr.pathname, sndgetattr.stbuf, sizeof(struct stat));
printf("Save status %s\n", reply->str);//that shows +OK
freeReplyObject(reply);
```

And then When I try to get my data back, I use

```
...
reply = redisCommand(c, "HMGET %s stat", rcvgetattr.pathname);
printf("status %s\n", reply->str);
freeReplyObject(reply);
```

Because I do not know which part contains my structure, so I use **gdb** and try to find it out. I use commands like `disp (struct stat)reply->str` or `disp (struct stat)reply->element->str` to see if the data is equal to the one I just saved. But I failed.

Does anyone know where it stores its data?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are having is that `HMGET` returns an array, not a string. Try using `reply->element[0]->str`.

This sample code may also help

```
typedef struct mytest {
    int myInt;
    long myLong;
} mytest;

// ...
mytest t;
t.myInt = 5; t.myLong = 123451;
reply = redisCommand(c, "HMSET %s stat %b", "mykey", &t, sizeof(mytest));
printf("Save status %s\n", reply->str);//that shows +OK
freeReplyObject(reply);

reply = redisCommand(c, "HMGET %s stat", "mykey");
mytest* response = reply->element[0]->str;
printf("status %d %ld\n", response->myInt, response->myLong);
freeReplyObject(reply);
```

Comment: Already solved! it is the ->str, but the thing is when using %b, I need pass a pointer to it, not the structure itself

Comment: this works for me but I get "warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type" at     mytest* response = reply->element[0]->str;